# Print preview default print differs from just normal print

Tags: internet-explorer, printing, internet-explorer-10

Okay sorry if the title is confusing but here is the issue and i could not find any mention of this exact problem anywhere else.

This started as a possible programming issue but I narrowed it down to actually being a IE and maybe just IE10 problem. I have an webpage that is nothing but an image I am printing. When I go to print preview, without touching any controls, it is stretched to fit the page perfectly and if I print from there, it looks like it should. However, if I just go to the print dialog box and print, it gets shrunk down to about 70% of the size of the page.

Does anyone know why this happens and any fixes for it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue you could try to reset IE:

1. Tools Icon (Alt+X)
2. Internet options from the drop down
3. Click the advanced tab
4. Click the reset button at the bottom
5. Click Apply